# sqoop export hive table 's specific column with different order to mysql using --columns param on Cloudera QuickStart VM

Tags: sqoop

I want to export and bind hive table column to mysql table's specified column having different columns order but same datatypes.

I have tried below command in cloudera QuickStart VM

i am trying to bind cols of source _tb to Dest_tb.

> sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_export --username root --password cloudera --table mysql_tb_name --columns order_date, revenue_demo --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/source_db/source_tb --input-fields-terminated-by "\001"--num-mappers 1

where columns are in order as appeared in source_tb and column_name are in order as appeared in Destinationtb with same data types.

ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for export

can someone point out my mistake, and correct me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Usually Hive warehouse directory contains the db folder name suffixed with ".db"

> --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/source.db/source_tb

Modifying db name should solve your problem.